# Показываются элементы только с определенным Id одежды (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Создал корзину условную для товаров, в ней есть свойства

```
public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }       

    public Longsleeve Longsleeve { get; set; }
    public int LongsleeveId { get; set; }    

}
```

В контроллере следующий код:

```
public IActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {

            Longsleeve longsleeve = db.Longsleeves.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            Cart cartItem = db.Cart.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LongsleeveId == id);
            if (cartItem == null)
            {
                db.Cart.Add(new Cart
                {
                    Quantity = 1,
                    Longsleeve = longsleeve,
                    LongsleeveId = longsleeve.Id
                });
            }

            else
            {
                cartItem.Quantity++;
                db.Cart.Update(cartItem);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(db.Cart.ToList());



    }
```

Проблема в том, что по адресу .../Home/AddToCart/1 (при вызове функции добавления в корзину) показывает только элементы в списке, у которых LongsleeveId = 1, а там где .../Home/AddToCart/2 только элементы, у которых LongsleeveId = 2. Как сделать так, чтобы показывались все элементы из БД? Что делаю не так?
[image: /Home/AddToCart/2]

Код из вьюхи:

```html
@model IEnumerable<ClothesStore.Models.Cart>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddToCart";
}

<h2>AddToCart</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
            </th>
        
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Longsleeve.Id)
            </th>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Longsleeve.BrandName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=> model.Longsleeve.Name)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Longsleeve.Price)
            </td>
           
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            </td>
          
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Longsleeve.Id)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Longsleeve.BrandName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Longsleeve.Name)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Longsleeve.Price)
            </td>

            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: По коду кажется что всё ок должно быть. Можете скрин по адресу `Home/AddToCart/1` тоже показать?
P.S. а вообще у вас должен быть отдельный yрл /Home/Cart, который показывает всю корзину, а AddToCart будет редиректить на него после добавления

Comment: Ну это временная мера была, поэтому хотел протестировать прям в AddToCart, но удивился, что не работает. Скрин прилагаю. https://pp.userapi.com/c850620/v850620725/168767/XzGnUPYCvrk.jpg

Comment: Странно действительно. Единственное предположение, что почему-то база не персистентна, то бишь хранит в памяти например, а не на диске, и между запросами всё старое удаляется

Comment: @DmitryDavydov при этом всём, в таблице Cart есть обе записи -- и для 1, и для 2 id

Comment: @DmitryDavydov я не очень понимаю, как это рабоатет, но я добавил в метод AddToCart строчку 
`  ViewBag.longsleeveModel = db.Longsleeves.ToList()` и всё заработало. Я не знаю, как до этого дошёл, но почему-то без неё не работает, при этом сам ViewBag.longsleeveModel я непосредственно в этом View не использовал. Можно это как-то объяснить?